# How may I have a black Diamond?

Tags: fonts, symbols

I sometimes want to make use of black operators corresponding to `\Box` and `\Diamond`. `\blacksquare` is a good blackened version of `\Box`, but `\blacklozenge` does not have quite the same shape as `\Diamond`. Are there other fonts I can access to resolve the problem?

No, \blacklozenge does not have the same shape as \Diamond and the question referred to has other concerns than mine.

Comment: There are four different solutions in the linked duplicate. Do none of them help? If so show why with a sample document and the question can be reopened.

Comment: The most satisfactory solution for the purposes I expressed is to set \rotatebox[origin=c]{45}{$\blacksquare$}.